# Stuck on "org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property.."

Tags: spring, jsp

Im making an update page with query. When I execute it, following error occurs.

```
    2013. 12. 16 오후 9:51:47 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
: Servlet.service() for servlet ebsm-pot-servlet threw exception
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Conflicting getter definitions for property "dateRange": groove.spring.data.domain.Condition#isDateRange(0 params) vs groove.spring.data.domain.Condition#getDateRange(0 params)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:740)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(StdSerializerProvider.java:344)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:39)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.MapSerializer._findAndAddDynamic(MapSerializer.java:403)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:257)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:186)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:23)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:610)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:256)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1606)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView.renderMergedOutputModel(MappingJacksonJsonView.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
```

This is my **Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/encodeRegModDo")
public String encodeRegModDo(HttpServletResponse response,
                        HttpServletRequest request,
                        ModelMap model,
                        Condition condition,
                        @RequestParam Map<String, Object> maps,
                        @ModelAttribute Encode encode) throws Exception {

    if(!PotSessionUtils.isAdminLogin()) {
        PotSessionUtils.goAdminMainPage(response);
    } else {            

        EncodeRepository.updateReg(encode);

        model.addAttribute("condition", condition);         
    }       

    return "redirect:/innovativepot/encodeMng/encodeRegList";
}
```

And **Repository**

```
@Statement(id="Encode.updateReg")
public void updateReg(Encode encode);
```

Can anyone help me out solving the error? If more info is needed, plz let me know.

**Condition**

```
 private String prcsSno;

public String getPrcsSno() {
return prcsSno;
```

}

public void setPrcsSno(String prcsSno) {
    this.prcsSno = prcsSno;

Comment: Let's see your `Condition` class. Also, I don't think you are showing us the correct handler method.

Comment: you mean page where you set Getter and Setter, right?

Comment: Yes, you seem to have two candidate getters for the same field.

Comment: I just edited it. Hope it helps!!

Comment: No, post the whole class. And post your servlet context configuration as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you everything you need to know. The `groove.spring.data.domain.Condition` class has two getters for the property `dateRange`:

- `isDateRange()`
- `getDateRange()`

Jackson does not know which one to use to serialize the object. So either remove or rename one or tell Jackson which one to use / ignore. If the class is yours then I'd prefer the first solution. Something cannot **be** a date range and **have** a date range at the same time.